# Set ((a and b) or (c and d)) in querydsl BooleanBuilder

Tags: spring, jpa, querydsl

I make some condition with querydsl.

I want make
`where ~~ and ((A or B) and (C or D))`  statements.

So, this is my code

```
...
BooleanBuilder tempBuilder = new BooleanBuilder();
for (SiteStatus status: siteStatus) {
   if (status.equals(SiteStatus.SERVICE)) {
        tempBuilder.or(Expressions.predicate(Ops.WRAPPED,
              (serviceBillInfo.status.ne(BillStatus.DELETE).and(serviceBillInfo.billType.eq(BillType.TRIAL)))));
   } else if (status.equals(SiteStatus.PAID)) {
        tempBuilder.or(Expressions.predicate(Ops.WRAPPED,
               (serviceBillInfo.status.ne(BillStatus.DELETE).and(serviceBillInfo.billType.ne(BillType.TRIAL)))));
   } else {
        tempBuilder.or(Expressions.predicate(Ops.WRAPPED,
               (serviceBillInfo.status.eq(BillStatus.DELETE).or(serviceBillInfo.billType.isNull()))));
        }
   }
builder.and(tempBuilder); //builder is BooleanBuilder and  has another conditions
...
```

I check this code with debugging, than can see this value with String

```
 ((serviceBillInfo.status != DELETE && serviceBillInfo.billType = TRIAL) 
    || (serviceBillInfo.status != DELETE && serviceBillInfo.billType != TRIAL) 
     || (serviceBillInfo.status = DELETE || serviceBillInfo.billType is null))
```

But after that, if I go inside the conditional statement from the query factory

```
and (
   servicebil3_.status<>? 
   and servicebil3_.bill_type=? 
   or servicebil3_.status<>? 
   and servicebil3_.bill_type<>? 
   or servicebil3_.status=? 
   or servicebil3_.bill_type is null
)
```

The query statement is executed as follows.

Is there any solution for this problems?

I changed this for BooleanExpressions, but it can be null, so I can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following code which uses QueryDSL to execute the where clause of your condition and ((A or B) and (C or D)):

```java
QServiceBill serviceBill = QServiceBill.serviceBill;
var theQuery = new JPAQuery<ServiceBill>(entityManager)
        .from(QServiceBill.serviceBill)
        .where(serviceBill.example.eq("example")
                .and(serviceBill.status.ne(BillStatus.DELETE)
                        .or(serviceBill.billType.eq(BillType.TRIAL)))
                .and(serviceBill.status.eq(BillStatus.DELETE)
                        .or(serviceBill.billType.eq(BillType.SUBSCRIPTION))));

List<ServiceBill> serviceBillList = theQuery.fetch();
```

The generated SQL statement would be:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        count(servicebil0_.service_bill_id) as col_0_0_ 
    from
        public.service_bills servicebil0_ 
    where
        servicebil0_.example=? 
        and (
            servicebil0_.status<>? 
            or servicebil0_.bill_type=?
        ) 
        and (
            servicebil0_.status=? 
            or servicebil0_.bill_type=?
        )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But, in my case, conditions may not exists. (You can see if condition)
So, I use BooleanBuilder and add conditions if it exists.

Comment: Oh, I missed that. The conditional statement from the query factory is completely correct. The order of operations will be 'and' before 'or'. Therefore, the SQL query can be understood as follows:

(servicebil3_.status<>? and servicebil3_.bill_type=?) or (servicebil3_.status<>? and servicebil3_.bill_type<>?) or servicebil3_.status=? or servicebil3_.bill_type is null

It is completely consistent with the string you see in the debug output.

Comment: Oh, I missed that if `siteStatus` have all conditions, I do not use condition statements for search all. So, I should check conditions, before for loop. In conclusion, I need some conditions, for example: "(servicebil3_.status<>? and servicebil3_.bill_type=?) or (servicebil3_.status<>? and servicebil3_.bill_type<>?)" // " (servicebil0_.status=? or servicebil0_.bill_type=?  ))" like this.